# Why doesn't my UL background-color cover LI elements?

Tags: html, css, menu, background-color

When setting a background on my `<ul>`, the `background-color` doesn't cover its `<li>` children elements (their `background` doesn't change). If I set `background` for `<a>` as well, that element's `background` changes but a thin underline appears: https://codepen.io/Boryamba/pen/XWJpzvE

I want `<li>` elements to have same `background-color` as my top-menu.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
* {
    padding         : 0;
    margin          : 0;
    box-sizing      : border-box;
    background-color: #546a76;
}
.page-content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 8fr 8fr 1fr;
}
.top-header {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: .5fr 7fr;
    height: 100vh;
}
.top-menu-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 1rem;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    background-color: #37454d;
}
.top-menu-list a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<body class="page-content">
    <header class="top-header">
        <nav class="top-menu">
            <ul class="top-menu-list">
                <li><a href="#about">Lorem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services">Lorem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contacts">Lorem</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the background-color to the * element, which is applying that background color to every element on the page. So even when you apply a different background-color to the ul element, the li will still have a background-color equal to what you set in the * element. Remove the background-color from the * and apply it elsewhere if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `background-color` on your asterisk `*` universal selector. It will set the background color of every element that doesn't have a background color set already.

To achieve the intended effect, instead set the background color of your `.page-content` body element.

```css
* {
    padding         : 0;
    margin          : 0;
    box-sizing      : border-box;
}

.page-content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 8fr 8fr 1fr;
    background-color: #546a76;
}

.top-header {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: .5fr 7fr;
    height: 100vh;
}

.top-menu-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 1rem;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    background-color: #37454d;
}

.top-menu-list a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 150%;

}
```

```html
<body class="page-content">
    <header class="top-header">
        <nav class="top-menu">
            <ul class="top-menu-list">
                <li><a href="#about">Lorem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services">Lorem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contacts">Lorem</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```